# How can I protect the Android code from reverse engineering?

Tags: java, android, reverse-engineering, reverse

Is there a way to protect the Android application code from reverse engineering or de-compiling?

For example coding the code or any other method in order to maintain our effort in programming and prevent others from accessing our code?

Comment: You cannot. Only code on servers is safe.

Comment: One at least somewhat possible way is using JNI (thus C code) with Android NDK - this is way harder to reverse engineer but far away from being safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer you cant. If you dont want anyone getting information on your application, dont put it there.

Longer answer? You would need some sort of server and a well written API (REST) where you can do callbacks to files (json). If you prefer not to write your own API, then you can use Parse-Server and use their Cloud Code.... or, use Firebase and use their Cloud Code functionality.

I personally use Parse-Server... but either will be just fine.

You also want to make sure you authenticate the json files so not one else can write to them. Depending on the app, maybe only users can read them. Again, Parse-Server/Firebase make this easy to do.